# How to define a few @property properties at the same time in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary in some class,

```
self.tables={'tableA':df_a,'tableB':df_b,...,'tableZ':df_z}
```

and a corresponding list of indices for each dataframe:

```
self.indices={'tableA':indices_a,'tableB':indices_b,...,'tableZ':indices_z}
```

The idea is that when the user of my class writes

```
someClass.tableA
```

he will get

```
self.tables['tableA'].iloc(self.indices['tableA'])
```

and when he will set it eg

```
someClass.tableA=some_df
```

He will actually change the corresponding indices.

I know how to do this with 26(26 comes from the a-z portion) @property
and other 26 @property.setter,for instance:

```
@propery
def tableA(self):
    return self.tables['tableA'].iloc[self.indices['tableA']]
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: You probably want to use a `__getattr__` hook here; `def __getattr__(self, name): if name in self.tables: return self.tables[name].iloc[self.indices[name]]` (and `raise AttributeError` if the name is not a valid table).

Comment: Thx,I suppose I'll need to use __setattr__ in the same manner (although it's invoked even if the attr does exist as opposed to __getattr__)

Comment: If `someInstance.tableA = ...` must work, then yes, implement `__setattr__` and call `super().__setattr__()` for anything that isn't a table name. Be careful with accessing attributes on `self` that have not yet been set, or access `self.__dict__` keys to avoid triggering further attribute lookups.